# remove duplicate values from items in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I check and remove duplicate values from items in a dictionary?
I have a large data set so I'm looking for an efficient method. The following is an example of values in a dictionary that contains a duplicate:

```
'word': [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10]), ('769819', [4, 10])]
```

needs to become

```
'word': [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10])]
```

Comment: There is no python dictionary in your question, just integers and strings and lists and tuples. What do you mean by "dictionary"?

Comment: the examples are the values of an item in a dictionary i have to show what it contains

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931672/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-do-a-sort-plus-uniq-on-a-python-list

Comment: once again, i am not using just a lists!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem essentially boils down to removing duplicates from a list of **unhashable** types, for which converting to a set does not possible.

One possible method is to check for membership in the current value while building up a new list value.

```
d = {'word': [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10]), ('769819', [4, 10])]}
for k, v in d.items():
    new_list = []
    for item in v:
        if item not in new_list:
            new_list.append(item)
    d[k] = new_list
```

*Alternatively*, use [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for a more concise answer, although **potentially** slower (*the list must be sorted first, if it is, then it is faster than doing a membership check*).

```
import itertools

d = {'word': [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10]), ('769819', [4, 10])]}
for k, v in d.items():
    v.sort()
    d[k] = [item for item, _ in itertools.groupby(v)]
```

**Output** -> `{'word': [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10])]}`

Comment: Added another approach, I would explore bench-marking the two approaches to see what works better with your dataset.

Comment: @mrdomoboto: Why `list()` wrapping genexpr? `[item for item, _ in itertools.groupby(v)]` is going to be faster/more succinct than a genexpr that just gets passed to `list` constructor anyway. Also, `groupby` is only slower if `list` is unsorted; if it's already sorted, as in the example, no sorting needed, so it's actually faster than any other solution in theory (`O(n)` with no meaningful constant factors). It could be optimized further if needed to push all work to C layer by changing comprehension to `list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), itertools.groupby(v)))` (`list()` wrapping is Py3 only).

Comment: You are correct, the `list()` wrapper does add another order of magnitude cost to that line. I've updated my answer. Yes, `groupby()` is far faster if the list is already sorted, which is why I added the note.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_list = [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10]), ('769819', [4, 10])]
new = []
for x in your_list:
    if x not in new: new.append(x)

print(new)    
>>>[('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10])]
```

Comment: That is a terrible misuse of list comprehensions. Don't use a `list` comprehension for side-effects. They're a functional construct, and functional code is side-effect free; using them for side-effects is wasteful (creates a garbage `list` of `None`s that just gets thrown away after) and confusing. Just use a plain `for` loop for those cases. Also, never name a variable `list`; shadowing built-ins is terrible practice.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I fixed it.

Comment: You did, but the new code has its own issues in the general case (no issues for the two-`tuple` case admittedly), since falsy values will be mistaken for duplicates by that test (a `list` like `[1, None, 0, 2]`, which has no duplicates, would still get reduced to `[1, 2]` because `None` and `0` look like duplicates to this logic). You could just do `if x not in new: new.append(x)` and avoid the `to_append` temporary and the risk of confusing falsy values for duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list, not a dictionary.  Python dictionaries may have only one value for each key.  Try

```
my_dict = dict([('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10]), ('769819', [4, 10])])
```

result:

```
{'769817': [6], '769819': [4, 10]}
```

a Python dictionary.  For more information https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: This does not return a list.

Comment: i do have multiple items as value

Answer (score 0):

Strikethrough applied to original question before edits, left for posterity:
<s>You're not using a `dict` at all, just a `list` of two-`tuple`s, where the second element in each `tuple` is itself a `list`. If you actually want a `dict`,</s>

```
dict([('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10]), ('769819', [4, 10])])
```

will convert it, and uniquify by key (so you'd end up with `{'769817': [6], '769819': [4, 10]}`, though it loses order, and doesn't pay attention to whether the values (the sub-`list`s) are unique or not (it just keeps the last pairing for a given key).

If you need to uniquify adjacent duplicates (where the values are important to uniqueness) while preserving order, and don't want/need a real `dict`, use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
nonuniq = [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10]), ('769819', [4, 10])]
uniq = [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(nonuniq)]
# uniq is [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10])]
# but it wouldn't work if the input was
# [('769819', [4, 10]), ('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10])]
# because the duplicates aren't adjacent
```

If you need to collapse non-adjacent duplicates, and don't need to preserve order (or sorted order is fine), you can use `groupby` to get a `O(n log n)` solution (as opposed to naive solutions that create a new list and avoid duplicates by checking for presence in the new list at `O(n^2)` complexity, or `set` based solutions that would be `O(n)` but require you to convert sub-`list`s in your data to `tuple`s to make them hashable):

```
# Only difference is sorting nonuniq before grouping
uniq = [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(nonuniq))]
# uniq is [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10])]
```

Comment: i am using a dictionary. i have multiple tuples for 1 key

Comment: @Brutalized: Your original question didn't make that clear. In any event, the last two options are more optimized versions of the current accepted answer (if the data is already ordered, the non-sorting `groupby` is `O(n)`, if it needs sorting, it's `O(n log n)`, both of which are a major improvement on `O(n^2)` of the loop with `list` contain checking on every iteration).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
I am just focusing on the list part:

```
>>> s = [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10]), ('769819', [4, 10])]
>>> [(x,y) for x,y in {key: value for (key, value) in s}.items()]
[('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10])]
>>>
```

Comment: That list comprehension could simplify to just: `dict(s).items()` (`list(dict(s).items())` on Py3). No need to turn everything into a comprehension when the data is already what the constructors expect. It also only uniqifies by the first element in the `tuple`, not the second, and does not preserve order, which may not match requirements. It's efficient if that's acceptable though.

Comment: thats very thoughtful and much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can uniqify the items based on the hash they generate. Hash could be anything, a sorted `json.dumps`, or `cPickle.dumps`.
This one liner can uniqify your dict as required.

```
>>> d =  {'word': [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10]), ('769819', [4, 10])]}
>>> import json
>>> { k: { json.dumps(x,sort_keys = True):x for x in v}.values() for k,v in d.iteritems()}
{'word': [('769817', [6]), ('769819', [4, 10])]}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```py
    def remove_duplicates(d: dict):
        unique_values = set(d.values())
        o = {}
        for k, v in d.items():
           if v in unique_values:
                o[k] = v
                unique_values.remove(v)
        return o
```