# Is set deterministic?

Tags: python

When reading such questions as [Get unique values from a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python) you can see the remarks the order can be not preserved.

This is understandable. What is bugging me that it goes farther -- as I can see the execution is not even deterministic, i.e:

```
list(set(values_list))
```

I will get the unique values, the problem is with each run the outcome would be in different order. So this would mean `set` (constructor or enumerator) is not deterministic.

I wonder how it happened? I don't see a reason why on single thread execution (?) you would get non-deterministic behavior.

*Sure, one can sort the outcome to enforce deterministic behavior, but you can get such idea once you observe you have non-deterministic code at hand.*

**Update:**

The essence of my code -- the file is a pickle with array of 10 000 strings (with 3 unique values).

```
combined = pickle.load(open("labels.p", "rb"))
label_keys = list(set(combined))
print(label_keys)
```

At each run I get different order. Oh, I use Python 3.6.4.

Comment: Sets are *unordered*. So converting a set to a list is not guaranteed to have the same outcome every time.

Comment: to clarify, is this question: "why is the set constructor non-deterministic?"

Comment: @mkrieger1 That doesn't mean it's *random* every time though. ***Unless it is: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2012-March/009394.html***

Comment: Can you show an example? When I tried, `list(set(values))` always game the same order (tested with a list of random numbers, both with 3.6 and 2.7)

Comment: this question might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/3812429/5986907

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets

Comment: @deceze why a dict question as the duplicate? this is about sets/lists

Comment: @tobias_k, I updated the question.

Comment: @Joel Because the answer applies to dicts and sets equally.

Comment: Also see the Note at the end of [the `__hash__` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), re: "values of `str`, `bytes` and `datetime` objects are “salted” with an unpredictable random value".

Comment: @tobias_k It's about hashing. Integers hash to themself, with no salting.

Comment: @tobias_k Really? Was that over separate runs? The hash of a string won't change during an execution run, that would be disastrous. But try running this a few times: `python3 -c "print({str(i) for i in range(9)})"`

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah, good point. No, it was indeed in the same interactive session. Silly me...

Answer (score -4):

I don't see this problem so far:

```
>>> values_list = range(100) * 3
>>> a = list(set(values_list))
>>> b = list(set(values_list))
>>> a == b
True
>>>
```

Comment: That is coincidence.

Comment: "I got the same result twice in a row" is not proof of deterministic behaviour.

Comment: On what version of Python…?

Comment: @deceze OP did not specify any particular version

Comment: Sure, but the version [is important](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14959001/476).