# Python eliminate duplicates of list with unhashable elements in one line

Tags: python, list-comprehension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: removing duplicates from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/python-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists)

Say i have list

```
a=[1,2,1,2,1,3]
```

If all elements in a are hashable (like in that case), this would do the job:

```
list(set(a))
```

But, what if

```
a=[[1,2],[1,2],[1,3]]
```

?

Comment: These you could turn into tuples before adding to the set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: removing duplicates from a list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/python-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479897/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python

Comment: Just realized this is a duplicate of many other questions, it should be closed.

Comment: The example in the question is a duplicate but the question is not duplicate. Consider other unhashable types such as a list containing duplicate pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Python 2

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,3]]
>>> [k for k,v in groupby(sorted(a))]
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Works also in Python 3 but with caveat that all elements must be orderable types.

Comment: This won't work if the elements cannot be compared (e.g. `[[1,2], [1,2], ['bug']]`). But maybe you could do `sorted(a, key=repr)` to fix that.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ah i get what you mean. You are talking about how in Python 3 `sorted` will give `unorderable types` in that case. Back when i answered this question Python 3 was not popular so this was a Python 2 answer. I'll update to mention that

Answer (score 0):

This set comprehension works for the List of Lists to produce a set of tuples:

```
>>> {(tuple(e)) for e in a}
set([(1, 2), (1, 3)])
```

Then use that to turn it into a list of lists again with no duplicates:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in {(tuple(e)) for e in a}]
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```