# Removing duplicated dictionaries from list

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, duplicates

I have list with dictionaries with same keys and different values, but sometimes could be duplicates:

```
[{'colorName': u'red',
  'color_thumb': [],
  'main_zoom_picture': u'webcontent/0007/991/393/cn7991393.jpg',
  'pic_uris': [(u'S', u'webcontent/0007/991/248/cn.jpg')],
  'swatch_image_path': u'webcontent/0007/991/248/cn7991248.jpg'},
 {'colorName': u'red',
  'color_thumb': [],
  'main_zoom_picture': u'webcontent/0007/991/393/cn7991393.jpg',
  'pic_uris': [(u'S', u'webcontent/0007/991/248/cn.jpg')],
  'swatch_image_path': u'webcontent/0007/991/248/cn7991248.jpg'}]
```

I'm doing:

```
[dict(tupleized) for tupleized in set(tuple(item.items()) for item in shared_list)]
```

And receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the trick on your set of data for me.

```
from itertools import groupby

print [k for k,v in groupby(sorted(shared_list))]
```

Taken [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784390/python-eliminate-duplicates-of-list-with-unhashable-elements-in-one-line)

Comment: Breaks on Python 3, though, since dicts are no longer comparable.

Comment: @Cristoph Hegemann: Is the a way to print also the duplicate dicts?

Answer (score 1):

You have your loops inverted; you need to loop over `shared_list` *first:

```
[dict(tupleized) for item in shared_list for tupleized in set(tuple(item.items()))]
```

A list comprehension lists the loops in nesting order; left is outermost.

Next problem is that your values contain lists, these cannot be added to a set unaltered.

Next is that you need to use the set *externally* to the loop to test if a dictionary has been seen before:

```
def immutable_repr(d):
    return tuple((k, tuple(v)) if isinstance(v, list) else v
                 for k, v in sorted(d.items()))

seen = set()
[d for d in shared_list if immutable_repr(d) not in seen and not seen.add(immutable_repr(d))]
```

Here `immutable_repr()` takes care of producing an immutable tuple from each dictionary:

```
>>> immutable_repr(shared_list[0])
(u'red', ('color_thumb', ()), u'webcontent/0007/991/393/cn7991393.jpg', ('pic_uris', ((u'S', u'webcontent/0007/991/248/cn.jpg'),)), u'webcontent/0007/991/248/cn7991248.jpg')
```

The sorting ensures that even for dictionaries with a different key-order (which can alter based on the insertion and deletion history of the dictionary) the test for having seen it still works.

and `seen` is used to track which ones have been seen so far, to filter out any subsequent duplicates:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> seen = set()
>>> pprint([d for d in shared_list if immutable_repr(d) not in seen and not seen.add(immutable_repr(d))])
[{'colorName': u'red',
  'color_thumb': [],
  'main_zoom_picture': u'webcontent/0007/991/393/cn7991393.jpg',
  'pic_uris': [(u'S', u'webcontent/0007/991/248/cn.jpg')],
  'swatch_image_path': u'webcontent/0007/991/248/cn7991248.jpg'}]
```

Comment: You're still going to run into the problem of lists as values.

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @user3761151: there are more errors to deal with here, just a mo. Your whole concept doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Martijin Pieters' explanation is correct about your error in the list comprehension.  The items() returned for each dict in the list will be a list.  In other words, a set cannot hash a list of lists.

However, you can store a tuple of tuples within a set.  So you can make following change to your line of code.

```
>>> [dict(tupleized) for tupleized in set([tuple(tup for tup in item.items()) for item in shared_list]
```

Also, Christoph Hegemann's answer is very elegant.  If you have the time and inclination, please check itertools (I discovered it recently and it's great to use).

My apologies to Christoph, because I would up-vote your answers but I just became a community member recently.  So I have no rep :(