# Remove duplicate sets from lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this `[(1,2), (2,1), (3,4), (5,6), (6,5)]`. How I can remove in python 3 one of sets with duplicate numbers? I want to get in output `[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]`.

Comment: Does it need to be a list of sets? Do you care about the order of the sets? Also, as you have it listed it's a list of tuples.

Comment: So (6,5) is the same as (5,6) then?

Comment: @RobertB yep, the same

Comment: if you don't care about the order: `list(map(tuple, set(map(frozenset, [(1,2), (2,1), (3,4), (5,6), (6,5)])))` See [Python eliminate duplicates of list with unhashable elements in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10784390/4279)

Comment: similar question: [Python: removing duplicates from a list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2213923/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order of the results doesn't matter, it is a one liner:

```
>>> x = [(1,2), (2,1), (3,4), (5,6), (6,5)]
>>> list(set([ tuple(set(i)) for i in x ]))
[(1, 2), (5, 6), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: @Robᵩ original order isn't required