# How do I resolve "Unhashable Type" when using sets?

Tags: python, set, maya

I am porting my Maya tool from python2 to python3 and ran into an issue where I have been using `set()` to remove duplicate entries in a list. Previously this worked great, but now I am getting:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'MeshUV'
```

The lists contain pymel MeshUV objects and might look like this:

```
[MeshUV('Right_Hand.map[1011]'), MeshUV('Right_Hand.map[1012]'),
 MeshUV('Right_Hand.map[1013]'), MeshUV('Right_Hand.map[1014]')]
```

Klaus D asked for minimal code to get this error, so use this in Maya with some uvs selected.

```
import pymel.core as pm
uvs = pm.ls(sl=True, fl=True)
set(uvs)
```

I don't know why this is suddenly a problem, but maybe there's any fast alternative to using set to remove duplicates or if I can alter the lists somehow to make them work again?

Edit: So after martineau's response I am thinking it's a change in Maya 2022 and rather than python3 per se, even though this is the version of Maya when they made the switch.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784390/python-eliminate-duplicates-of-list-with-unhashable-elements-in-one-line

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example and show us the full error traceback!

Comment: `MeshUV` apparently isn't [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable).

Comment: Nothing changed between Python 2 & 3 that would have affected this, i.e. it wouldn't have worked in Python 2 either — something else is the problem.

Comment: Details would also help: you say it works in Python 2, but under the same version of Maya , or another version of Maya? Try running the same Maya with -pythonver 2 command line arguments and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Python requires items in a set or dictionary to be *hashable*. If you're not using a custom type in which you can define `__eq__` and `__hash__` functions, you're better off using a different method of removing duplicates:

```py
new_list = list()
for item in old_list:
    if item not in new_list:
        new_list.append(item)
```

Comment: Actually Python only requires the *keys* of a dictionary to hashable, that values associated with each one doesn't have to be.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for the info :)