# Regex :How to remove repetition of the same string?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to find the year from the date.
the dates are in the format

```
"Nov.-Dec. 2010"
"Aug. 30 2011-Sept. 3 2011"
"21-21 Oct. 1997"
```

```
my regular expression is
q = re.compile("\d\d\d\d")
a = q.findall(date)
```

so obviously in the list it has two items for a string like `"Aug. 30 2011-Sept. 3 2011"`

```
["2011","2011"]
```

i dont want a repetition, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following function :

```
def getUnique(date): 
  q = re.compile("\d\d\d\d") 
  output = [] 
  for x in q.findall(date): 
     if x not in output: 
         output.append(x) 
  return output
```

It's O(n^2) though, with the repeated use of not in for each element of the input list

see [How to remove duplicates from Python list and keep order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479897/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a backreference in the regex (see the syntax [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)):

```
(\d{4}).*\1
```

Or you could use the current regex and put this logic in the python code:

```
if a[0] == a[1]:
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry I can't give you more than +1

Comment: Then please mark his answer as correct by checking the green V near it!