# How to trim a list with duplicated elements in Python?

Tags: python, list

I wish to trim the list

`[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3, ... , 145,145,145]`

into

```
[0,1,2,3,4,...,145]
```

I know the "C-Programming-style" way of doing it in Python.

**I am here to ask for an intelligent and smart way of doing this.**

Comment: numpy.unique for example

Comment: @Josh  Inspect carefully and then speak. If I use the solution given there, I would end up with an empty list.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, moderators.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng That question asked what you are asking with one more step afterwards. All you needed was the first step. If you need another duplicate question closer to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479897/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-if-the-item-order-is-not-impo

Comment: If the items are in order as in your example, use itertools.groupby

Comment: The question is unclear... unfortunately. Is this like set op, set + sort, or Unix style uniq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.unique(mylist)` or `list(set(mylist))` should do.

PS And it is not 'trimming' - that's a different thing...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
unique = [x for x in set(original)]
```

or

```
unique = list(set(original))
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

`print list(set(my_list))`