# Why is sorted(set(A)) faster than set(sorted(A))?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, set, time-complexity

I have an array of numbers. I want to sort them and remove duplicates. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/479917/3277111) answer suggest to use `set` and `sort` for that kind of operation. The order of operations shouldn't change the results, so I measured the time of computations.

```
from numpy.random import randint
from time import clock

n = 1000000

A=randint(0,n,n)

t1=clock()
B=sorted(set(A))
t2=clock()
C=set(sorted(A))
t3=clock()

print t2-t1, t3-t2

>>> 0.48011 1.339263
```

sorted(set(A)) is roughly three times faster than set(sorted(A)).

What makes the one faster than the other? Also, is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: because `set(A)` is of small size than `A`

Comment: You have to sort a much smaller number of values...

Comment: `set(sorted(A))` won't actually give you the results in sorted order. Sets are unordered.

Comment: True. You need to do `sorted(set(sorted(A)))`.

Comment: @Barmar You just need `sorted(set(A))`.

Comment: True, but that's the other code that he's comparing with. I was just pointing out that if you sort first, then remove duplicates, you have to sort again.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some timed examples. Hope it helps.

Comment: set(A) is smaller than A. But removing duplicates from ordered list should be faster too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because when you call:

`set(sorted(A))`

you are sorting the original full list and then filtering out the duplicate values. However, when you call:

`sorted(set(A))`

you are first shortening the list by removing duplicate values using `set` and then sorting the much smaller list hence the shorter time.

Hope that makes sense.

#### For Example

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
>>> A = sorted(A)
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]

>>> set(A)
{1, 2, 3}

On the other hand:

>>> A = [3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1]
>>> A = set(A)
{3, 2, 1}

>>> sorted(A)
{1, 2, 3}
```

And as @Barmar said, sorting is much slower than removing duplicates therefore there is a real time gain when you have to sort a much smaller list (1/4 of the list in my example above)

### Time Benchmarking

```
a = [1,2,3] * 10000

set(sorted(a)) --> 0.1890001297
sorted(set(a)) --> 0.0079998970
```

Comment: Also important is that sorting is slower than removing duplicates.

Comment: So how slow is sort compared to set operation?

Comment: @ysakamoto, That really depends on how ordered your list is and how many duplicate values are in there. Try running this demo I made a few times: http://repl.it/R3I

Comment: But just saying "sorting is slower than removing duplicates" does not mean much. It is obvious from my benchmark. I want to know why sort is slower than set.

Comment: @ysakamoto, because sorting involves a whole bunch of processes such as searching, deleting, inserting, shifting, etc. Whereas set just goes through a list and takes those variables that it wants. Something like `[i for i in input_list if i not in already_list]`. Something like that.

Comment: @ysakamoto. If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you.

Comment: Because set uses an expected O(n) time algorithm using hash tables and sorting is Omega(n log n) and the constant factor is rather low in both cases