# Fastest way to remove duplicates from a list of comparable, unhashable items

Tags: python, list, duplicates

How can I remove duplicate items from a list if all I know is that the list elements can be ordered?  (I also don't care about the order of items in the list.)

Existing questions like [How to remove duplicates from Python list and keep order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479897/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-if-the-item-order-is-not-impo) or [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/python-removing-duplicates-in-lists) require the use of a set, i.e. require the items in the list to be hashable.
**In my case, hashability is not a guarantee.**

Comment: It is an absurd requiremen for the quesion "how can I remove duplicates from a list" -- a list can contain ANYTHING, so it really doesn't answer the question, does it?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 please reopen. It took me a long time to find this and John La Rooy's answer is awesome!

Comment: wow, that comment is pretty buried as the third answer down, and really the comment on the comment is the answer. But whatever.

Comment: What about letting a Python set doing all the work? `list(set(list))` Does a set require hashable elements?

Comment: Yes, a set requires hashable elements. `set([{'a': 2}])` throws `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. If I want to remove duplicates from a list of dicts I can not use the "duplicates" those users marked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling sorted on an already sorted list has negligible overhead in Python. It's not really worth adding the extra complexity and the possibility that someone accidentally passes the wrong parameter to function

```
from itertools import groupby
def remove_duplicates(data):
    ''' Remove duplicates from the data (normally a list).
        The data must be sortable and have an equality operator
    '''
    data = sorted(data)
    return [k for k, v in groupby(data)]
```

Comment: nice! I didn't realize itertools groupby could be used in this way, this is briliant! Looking at the groupby code it looks like the "k" doesn't even need to be hashable, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Since the question is asking about "fastest", comparison results shall probably be added to back the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: See John La Rooy's answer for a better one.

Again, ths solution only works on a sortable list. If you pre-sorted it (really the objects only need to be **grouped**) you could set sort=False and then it would only need the comparison operator.

```
def remove_duplicates(data, sort=True):
    ''' Remove duplicates from the data (normally a list).
        The data must be sortable and have an equality operator
    '''
    if not data:
        return data
    if sort:
        data = sorted(data)
    out = [data[0]]
    for i, n in enumerate(data[1:]):
        if data[i] != n:
            out.append(n)
    return out
```

Comment: You might as well define `__hash__` so you can use `set()`.

Comment: Rough testing, but your title says 'fastest', I seem to get faster results using `from itertools import izip_longest` and `out = [x for (x,y) in izip_longest(data,data[1:]) if x != y]`. Giving range(1000) * 3, so everything is triplicated, and pre-sorted, and run 10,000 iterations, it takes about 5 seconds with your code and 3.3 seconds with izip_longest, and the result lists == the same.

Comment: That's roughly what [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19135774/478656) suggests in one of the duplicate threads, but a) unrelated to numpy, b) I suspect they have a bug with missing the final list item if it's not a duplicate, and c) They're using the builtin zip which doesn't have the same kind of speedup when I try it. (Maybe in Python 3 it does?) The itertools version pads the shorter list with None and fixes the last item bug, I think, as well as being faster.

Comment: It would be faster to iterate over one extra item than to make this copy of a slice `data[1:]`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - Python 3's `zip()`, `itertools.zip_longest()`, `range()`, etc. already produce lazy objects instead of eagerly creating a `list`.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy what do you mean "faster to iterate over one extra item"? If I just do counting through the list in Python with an index counter starting at 1, it gets dramatically slower...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Defining __hash__ for mutables would be a rather bad idea.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy you are right. Actually, I should use islice from itertools

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I like that. I bet John La Rooy beat both of us though :)  Also, you forgot to sort.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy's answer comes out (in my same test block) approximately the same as mine, but if he only called sorted() when requested, it's ~15% faster on pre-sorted ones.