# From a text file I want to extract a single column and remove duplicates, ending up with a column with unique strings - python

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a text file separated by tabs and newlines. the first column contains sample IDs but these are duplicated:

```
1/16    info    info    info
1/16    info    info    info
2/16    info    info    info
2/16    info    info    info
2/16    info    info    info
3/16    info    info    info
3/16    info    info    info
```

I need to extract the first column of the IDs so I end up with a single column i.e-

```
1/16
2/16
3/16
```

I have managed to extract the column but I am having difficulty with removing the duplicates? Here is what I have:

```
path = ./Documents/*txt
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    my_file = open(filename, 'r+')
    for line in my_file:
        line = line.split('\t')
        id = line[0]
        print id
```

I have tried using another list and adding in the IDs and then

```
s=[]
if id not in s:
    s.append(id)
```

But i am stuck on how to remove the duplicates from here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicates from Python list and keep order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479897/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-python-list-and-keep-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understand what you want,
but you can remove duplicates from the list just with

```
list(set(foo))
```

for eample:

```
t = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
list(set(t))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
list(set(t) - set(s))
[8, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks I understand this but the problem I am having is that my 'list' of IDs is not a list. it is a set of strings

Comment: I thinks its much more easier if you work in this case with a list:
In your for just append every tring to a list, after that you'll have a list of all ids and you can remove the duplicates with the code snippet up

Comment: Yes I have tried this. However when i try:
    lst =[]
    lst.append(id)

I get each ID in its own list? Like:

[1/16]
[2/16]
etc? how can i change this? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Could you post your complete Code, becasue if I add  the declaration of a empty list and instead of the print the append function in your snippet in your questions
I get only one correct list. 
You could also try during the append:

lst.append(str[0])

Answer (score 0):

For file text processing (if you use linux) standard tool are better choice. 
In fact in your case you could use awk like.

```
# quick and dirty
import subprocess
def get_uniqid(path, suff):
    return set(subprocess.check_output(
        "awk '{print $1}' %s/*.%s | uniq" % (path, suff), shell=True).splitlines())
```

It will return the set of the id from the folder `path` with the suffix `suff`.

With you code just do

```
def get_ids():
    ids = []
    path = "./Documents/*txt"
    for filename in glob.glob(path):
        with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
            for line in fin:
                line = line.split('\t', maxsplit=2)
                id_ = line[0]
                if id_ not in ids:
                    ids.append(id_)
    return set(ids) # set removes duplicated not needed because of if id_ not in ids:
```

Answer (score 0):

using sets and set comprehension assuming you have tabs as separators:

```
print ({element.split("\t")[0] for element in set(open("sample.txt").readlines())})
```

Output:

```
>>>>
{'2/16', '1/16', '3/16'}
```